# Matlab issue: linprog

Tags: matlab, optimization, constraints, zero

Good evening,

I've got an issue with the linprog function of Matlab, here is the message I get:

> Exiting due to infeasibility: an all-zero row in the constraint
>   matrix does not have a zero in corresponding right-hand-side entry.

According to the help, it means that I have at least a row in Aeq that is full of zeros (let's say, row i), but that beq(i) is not equal to zero.

I checked my matrices doing:

```
checkmat=full(sum(abs(Aeq')))';
checkmat=horzcat(checkmat,beq);

for i=1:length(checkmat)
   if (checkmat(i,1)==0 && checkmat(i,2)~=0) || (checkmat(i,2)==0 && checkmat(i,1)~=0)
      i
   end
end
```

but it seems to be alright. Has anybody an idea about where it could come from?
If missing any information, I will gladly try to gather them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default interior-point method used by `linprog` performs some preprocessing steps before the actual iterations begin. Therefore, while your `Aeq` might not contain an all-zero row for which the corresponding element of `beq` is non-zero, this might occur after the preprocessing.

You could try running `linprog` using another algorithm (use `optimset('LargeScale', 'off')` and/or `optimset('LargeScale', 'off', 'Simplex', 'on')`) and see what the output is in that case.

However, I suspect that in all cases you'll get an "infeasible problem" exit flag, since your equality constraints seem to be impossible to satisfy.

[More info](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/linear-programming-algorithms.html) on Matlab's available linear programming algorithms and their preprocessing steps.

Comment: Thank you very much. For some reason, the simplex method seems far more stable...
My equality was possible to satisfy.

Something weird happened: I tried to find the maximum amount of energy one can yield with a network of dams, knowing the monthly discharges since 80 years. In flood periods, you cannot use all the water to produce power, so you open the doors, without any limitation in my model.

So I had a decision variable unbounded that I needed in the equality constrains (hydric balance). If the variable is limited between 0 and inf, it does not work, but 0 and 100^1000 is ok...

Mystery.